# Do turning bluetooth on with Android makes it a beacon?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, altbeacon

if i turn on bluetooth in iOS it will be discovered in beacon scanner, is it the same with Android?

Or we should turn the android to be a beacon explicitly using any **libraries** like alt beacon?

> What am trying to achieve is to get RSSI from android by **ONLY** enabling Bluetooth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.  Turning on bluetooth does not make mobile devices -- neither Android nor iOS -- advertise as beacons.**  If you want to make either platform advertise as a beacon, you must install a custom app that is programmed to start the advertising.  The Android Beacon Library has tools to do this on Android.  On iOS you can use built-in CoreLocation and CoreBluetooth.

On both iOS and Android, if you turn on Bluetooth from the settings screen and leave the settings screen up, it will emit both BLE and Bluetooth Classic packets to make it discoverable by external bluetooth scanning apps.  But these advertisements will absolutely not be BLE Beacon advertisements in the strict sense.  It is still possible to detect these non-beacon packets with some scanning apps.

Just enabling bluetooth on either platform *might* make it detectable based on what the other apps are doing.  There may be pre-existing apps on the phones that emit BLE beacon advertisements, BLE GATT service advertisements, or similar.  However, you cannot predict whether any individual device will do this because you can't predict what apps are installed. Nor can you know what advertisements random apps will emit in a way that is predictable.  **If you want to be able to rely on detecting another device with BLE in a predictable way you must get an app installed on that device.**

Comment: Thank you for a quick turn around.

Comment: The ios-beacon-tools project is not packaged as a binary framework, but there are instructions for using the source code.  Feel free to open new questions here on how to use it, or if you find bugs, open an issue on the GitHub repo.

Comment: It's not simple, but here is a tutorial on how to create a binary framework: https://www.raywenderlich.com/5109-creating-a-framework-for-ios  Because of the complexity, however, if you are having trouble following the instructions in the repo as-is, turning it into a binary framework will be a much bigger challenge.